# $.getJSON is slow

Tags: javascript, json

I am using `$.getJSON` to pull inventory of objects (100 items, not a large set) but its taking 8-10 seconds for XHR call.

Would like to learn if there is something I am missing or something I could do to expedite my program?

Comment: Figure out which part is slow first; is it making the initial request, is it the server-side generation, is it the time it takes to download that to the client, or is it the time to parse the data on the client side?

Comment: Please use some JavaScript profiling tools like the [Timeline](http://www.webkit.org/blog/1091/more-web-inspector-updates/#timeline_panel)/Profiles panel in WebKit’s developer tools.

Comment: I guess the initial request $.getJSON(blah)

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of things that can go wrong during the entire span of the request.

Here are a few notable areas you could check for bottlenecks, starting from the request to the response.

- **Is your browser/system/hardware capable?**

  Since this operation is JavaScript, older browsers like IE6, low-powered systems like netbooks and even weakly set-up systems which run too many applications at a given time may suffer the consequences.
- **Is the browser instantly executing the task? Or was it delayed?**

  Busy JavaScript is the culprit here. JavaScript is single-threaded and too many operations can and will bog down the browser and may delay queued tasks from running. An example of a scenario which can make this happen is when your page contains too many JavaScript plugins, or contain code that is poorly coded, some of which might even use synchronous operations.
- **Could it be the PHP/JSP/[some other server-side language]?**

  Yes it could be. For example, PHP might be threaded per request but the operation of it's code is synchronous. If a line of PHP takes too long to execute, this comprises part of that delay. Until that line finishes, the server will never respond.
- **Do you use multiple/nested SQL queries?**

  Diving deeper into the server, multiple and/or nested SQL queries, especially for a commonly used operation can and will cause further delay. An advice is to limit your query only to what was supposed to be fetched, and not entire records. If nested queries can't be avoided, try a different method of retrieving that data.
- **Unoptimized function calls**

  This goes for both server-side and client-side scripts. Excessive operations could also be the cause of delays. Determine code that is excessively redundant and merge/shorten them. In JS, for example, simple condition-assignment operations can be done with ternary operations.
- **Looping too much?**

  Looping too much is also one common cause of delays. One mistake in SQL is to retrieve all rows and count them in PHP instead of using the built-in `COUNT()` in SQL. The error is two-fold, you return too much data from SQL, and second you are counting/looping over too many items in PHP.
- **Are you on dial-up or what?**

  Bandwidth is essential, hence size matters. And so, limit your return data only to what was needed. The main reason developers prefer JSON was it's smaller size compared to XML as well as marked-up content. To add to that, you can also compress your return data with gzip compression.

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to reduce the size of JSON file read from $.getJSON ?

Comment: As far as I know, from PHP, the `json_encode()` encodes data into JSON that is not pretty-printed and therefore already compact. To add to that, the server can compress using GZIP for transmission, that is if the browser supports retrieving content GZIPped.

Answer (score 2):

There are many things involved on it. Two main bottleneck I think are these

- The server script generating the JSON might be causing the problem or taking long process time to generate the output.
- You have too many scripts on your page like effect or slider, that the getJSON, is running slow

In most of the cases, the first one is a silent killer. In order to test your script, make a getJSON request to page, which simply displays the JSON string, without any processing. Something very lightweight like this

```
{ "test" : "value" }
```

In PHP

echo ' { "test" : "value" }';

And make a `getJSON` request to this page and check if the script is running fast. In case it is fast, the problem is in your server script.

Comment: Is there a way to access the JSON file by making the query once and storing it in an object locally ?

Comment: @AbhishekKumar, using sessions as `$_SESSION['backup']` is perfect way for this

Comment: can you share more about $_SESSION ['backup']. sorry I am new to js

Comment: `$_SESSION ['backup']` is a php command for storing/retrieving some data in and from the server, so that it is available in the next page or next point. You can do a ajax request through jquery to a page, which stores the json value to a session, so next time, instead of querying for a json, query a simple page, which simply will give the json, already available at session.

Comment: I used $.ajax and the program is much faster now. thanks everyone